# Change slide automatically in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to move one slide to another slide automatically 
with time faster than

> \transduration{0.00}

In fact, I want to make it user's specified time say 0.01 sec. 
Is is possible in Beamer?

Comment: Do you want to create some kind of animation? A hundredth second is very fast. Common video with 25 frames per second has a duration of 0.04 s per frame. 0.01 s is likely beyond any viewer's capability and much less than the humans eye can perceive.

Comment: Depending on how complex your slides are and how fast you computer/viewer is, 0.01 s could be well below the time, your viewer needs to change slides.

Comment: Also notice that not all viewers support this feature.

Comment: Yes, I want to create animation kind of thing. Ok, in that case I will take 0.04 sec. duration.

Comment: You could try the `animate` package for in-slide animations.

Comment: @user12290 But beware that due to hardware limitations the real time can be slower.

Comment: @AlexG As your comment seems to have solved the question, would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Like this?

Comment: @AlexG Thank you! One unanswered question less, only 9,241 to go :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create animation effects, the `beamer` class offers the `\transduration` and the `\animate` commands that automatically change between successive slides in the full-screen mode of some PDF viewers. However, the duration of 0.04 s per frame is sufficient, if achieved by the viewer, to produce a smooth animation effect for the human's eye. This corresponds to a rate of 25 frames per second used by common video formats.

Alternatively, the `animate` package can be used to embed animations of external image files or inline graphics (TikZ, PSTricks, etc.) within a single slide/document page for display in Acrobat Reader or PDF-XChange.

Note however, that the achievable frame rate of either method depends on the complexity of the graphics and on the computer hardware.